# Why does abandoment rate not equal the inverse of funnel conversion rate?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics account. For a given time period, the abandonment rate on a single goal is `73.15%` on the "Goal Overview" page.

If I switch pages to the "Funnel Visualization" for the exact same goal and time period, I  have a `25.98%` funnel conversion rate.

Surely, if `25.98%` of funnel attempts resulted in a goal completion, then the remainder (`74.02%`) must have been abandonments?

`100 - 25.98 = 74.02`

`74.02 != 73.15`

Why are the two numbers different?

Comment: Rounding error (Google Analytics is not a precision tool) ? If possible try a larger timeframe.

Comment: I can't imagine it being a rounding error. Even rounding to whole numbers, it would be a 1% difference (74% vs 73%), and since GA shows everything to 2 d.p. it 's highly unlikely. Businesses use this data for forecasts and so on. A 1% increase in abandonment might make major differences to those forecasts, so if it's that inaccurate surely people wouldn't use it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was a flippant way of saying "that error is probably not significant". Sometimes differences for the same numbers in different reports are due to systematic differences (e.g. conversion reports overcount cpc visits at the expense of direct visits, multichannel visits do not), but mostly it's something harmless, e.g. that GA seemingly does not always use the same data sample in the reports. You can try to work around this by changing sample size (not applicable to funnels) or use a segment that includes all visitors (but still forces GA ot recalculate the report on the fly).

Comment: I was meaning to write "multichannel reports" in the above sentence, not "multichannel visits" (but then that was probably clear from context).